# How to implement an extra view for a game when it starts or gets interrupted

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multiview

I want to implement a view on which has "resume", "save" and "quit" buttons and it popups when the game is started or interrupted. I looked up a few books and most just mentioned animation of view's transition or suggested using tab bar controller, etc and all these are not applicable to my game's need. I would like to know:

1) How to implement it? Such as how to declare, how to call and and where it is called? Just create another ViewController class with .xib file? Then what? Just add it as a subview to window in delegate file like [window addSubview:viewController.view];?
2) How to make it appear after the startup intro screen and before the game starts?
3) How to make it appear on top of the game when the game is paused?
4) How to make it disappear when it is resumed?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a separate view controller and display it with `-presentModalViewController:animated:`.

Comment: Is it a method for instance of ViewController? How to implement it? I am newbie so would you mind give me more details on it? I have a customized subclass of UIView called MyView on which the game is drawn. So how to invoke the extra view from the main view so that the extra view can appear on top of the paused game? Any book or website would do the explanation or have samples?

Comment: it only works in any subclass of UIViewController and not any subclass of UIView?

Comment: `presentModalViewController:animated` is a method of `UIViewController` if you mean that. If you don't want to work with view controllers, you have to change the view hierarchy yourself (`-addSubview:`, `-removeFromSuperview`).